# Using FOR in a batch file with multiple files with multiple extensions

Tags: for-loop, cmd

I have three different file extensions that are used with a command line program.  The syntax of this program is `program.exe file1.bm file1.pal file1.ppm`.

It takes `file1.bm` and `file1.pal` and converts them into the `ppm` file.

I've tried using `for %%A in (.bm .pal .ppm) do call program.exe %%A`, but it won't work because `%%A` can't represent all three extensions.

How do I create a batch file using `FOR` (or an alternative) to fill in the required commands for the above syntax?

Thanks

Comment: `(*.bm *.pal *.ppm)` you were searching for files without names. That is legal but Explorer won't let you create them. If using a path you must specify the path before each filename. `(C:\*.bm C:\*.pal C:\*.ppm)`. It works with the `dir` and `del` commands too.

Comment: Windows' filenames are to the left of the LAST dot, and the extension to the right of the LAST dot. Other dots are just part of the name and aren't special.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  Even if I use the directory of each file, what commands do I use after "do call program.exe"

Comment: Once one of the files is found, what is it that needs to be done?

Comment: I'm trying to use wildcards in the batch program to automate the process of having to type out every single file.  There are hundreds of *.bm and *.pal files I need to convert into *.ppm.  I have to use the syntax of "bm2ppm file1.bm file1.pal file1.ppm" to convert each file into that ppm format.  How is this accomplished in a batch file?  This is all im asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for /F` and `dir /B` to get the desired result.
First we get every file matching a pattern (`*.bm`), check if the other file exist, then execute the command.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('dir /B *.bm') DO (
    %== Found a file to work with ==%
    if exist "%%~nF.pal" (
        %== Validated other file ==%
        bm2ppm "%%~F" "%%~nF.pal" "%%~nF.ppm"
    )
)
```

Be aware though, if you have special characters in your filename you would need to adjust your codepage using `chcp  Codepage`

If you dont mind having it search recursively, you can use `for /R %%F IN (*.bm) DO (` instead.

Make sure to look through `for /?` and `dir /?`

Answer (score 0):

```
set "passNum=0"
set folder=c:/xxxxxx/

For %%f in ("%folder%\*.bm") Do (
    set /a "passNum+=1"
)
For %%f in ("%folder%\*.pal") Do (
    set /a "passNum+=1"
)
For %%f in ("%folder%\*.ppm") Do (
    set /a "passNum+=1"
)

if %passNum% == 3 (
    rem  do converts them into the ppm file.
)
```

Using FOR in a batch file with multiple files with multiple extensions.